# Add a new file from a different path to an existing zip file in python

Tags: python, zip

I have a path and all the files in the path should be zipped and once the files are zipped I need to add different file from a different file path to the existing zip folder. I have written my code to create and zip the file from the first path. Is there any way by which I can append the files from the different path to the existing zip folder.

Here is my code:

```
def _create_zip_folder(self, zip_path, base_path, pattern='.*'):
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)    
    rootlen = len(base_path)
    patterns = pattern.split(",")      
    regex = re.compile('|'.join(fnmatch.translate(p) for p in patterns))
    for base, _, files in os.walk(base_path):
        for file in files:                
           if regex.match(file):
              fn = os.path.join(base, file)        
              zip.write(fn, fn[rootlen:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add to the end of the function:

```
some_other_path = '/some/other/path/a_file.ext'
name = some_other_path.split( os.path.sep )[-1]

zip.write( some_other_path, name )
```